# Python Mechanize: UnicodeEncodeError when uploading UTF-8 file. 'ascii' codec

Tags: python, mechanize

the mechanize framework works great for automating the first couple of web screens. The problem is where it needs to upload a file with in a form.

Here is the section of code just before the error:

```
br.select_form(name="form.uploadXMLDataWizardForm")
xmlFile = codecs.open("MyFile.xml", "rt", "utf8")
br.form.add_file(file_object=xmlFile, content_type="text/xml", filename="MyFile.xml", name="dataFile")
br.submit(name="$action:next")
```

It results in the following error at runtime:

```
    br.submit(name="$action:next")
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 541, in submit
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 530, in click
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/mechanize/_form.py", line 2999, in click
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/mechanize/_form.py", line 3201, in _click
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/mechanize/_form.py", line 2350, in _click
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/mechanize/_form.py", line 3269, in _switch_click
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/mechanize/_form.py", line 3252, in _request_data
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/mechanize/_form.py", line 1341, in _write_mime_data
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 650-651: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any idea how to make mechanize handle upload of a UTF-8 file?

Comment: Using `codecs.open()` makes the content read not UTF-8.

Comment: @Ignacio I have used codes.open successfully to read/write UTF-8 content before. What is your suggestion? :-)

Comment: Yes, you can use it to read files that are encoded in UTF-8, but what it gives you isn't UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mechanize seems to expect the file data as raw bytes, not Unicode data. Try opening the file using the usual `open()` function:

```
...
xmlFile = open("MyFile.xml", "rt")
...
```

Comment: That was it! I cannot believe it was so simple. Thanks!